# Explain this step-by-step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question from limits has been bothering me. Could anyone help me.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{(a^x + b^x +c^x/3) ^{1/x}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take exponentials and logarithms, we will get
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(a^x + b^x + c^x) - \log(3)}{x}\right)$$
Let us examine the inner limit. We can see that the inner limit is of the indeterminant form $\frac{0}{0}$. We apply L'Hopital's rule:
$$\overset{H}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^x\log a + b^x\log b + c^x\log c}{a^x + b^x + c^x}$$
Can you finish off the limit from here? Don't forget to exponentiate the final result.

Comment: You can only do this because the logarithm is a continuous function. This is a general result which relies on the continuity of the function.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I(sadly) did not know that the logarithm function could be applied inside the limit. Thank you again.